# Change Enumerator to Source in Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, stream, akka-stream, enumerate

I would like to convert the following code into something that replaces the `Enumerator` with a `Source` (using *Akka Streams* as recommmended to do in the [Play Framework migration documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/StreamsMigration25)):

```
   implicit def toEnumerator(stream: HtmlStream)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Enumerator[Html] = {
     // Skip empty chunks, as these mean EOF in chunked encoding
     stream.enumerator.through(Enumeratee.filter(!_.body.isEmpty))
   }
```

I particularly can't find what the equivalent would be to `enumerator.through`. All help appreciated!

Comment: Looks like you want `source.filter(_.body.nonEmpty)`.

Comment: @marcospereira thanks. That looks like it is to replace `Enumeratee.filter(!_.body.isEmpty)`. As mentioned I am mainly finding difficulty coming up with a replacement for the `stream.enumerator.through` part. I think that the `.through` is the function enabling empty chunks to be skipped (as mentioned in the commented out part)